having problem when writing in @tinymce/tinymce-react package
I have a project with next.js and tailwindcss, recently I installed  tinymce-react that is a text rich for react in my project but i can not type well, I checked my codes with chatgpt but it could not help me :

I checked apiKey and everything is okay.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Set the initialValue={} on load, but if you are using useState() to store the edited value, you want to set that to the value={} attribute.
example:
const [editedValue, setEditedValue] = useState(myObject.lifeStory);

....

<Editor
    ...
    value={editedValue}
    initialValue={myObject.lifeStory}
    onEditorChange={(content, editor) => { setEditedValue(content) }}
    ...
/>

